# Querying a list of tuples in Database

Tags: python, sql-server, list, tuples

Since I am new to python programming, I don’t know more about querying a data from a database.
First, I’ve created my database in SQL Server, with 2 columns: The `String` column and the `Numeric` column.

`+--------+---------+
| String | Numeric |
+--------+---------+
| One    |    1    |
| Five   |    5    |
| Three  |    3    |
| Seven  |    7    |
| Eight  |    8    |
| Two    |    2    |
+--------+---------+`

For example:

`X = [(‘three’,’odd’), (‘one’,’odd’), (‘two’,’even’)]`

Now I want that the output follow this sequence: `odd – even – odd` so it will be like this `1 2 3`.

`+-----+------+-----+
| Odd | Even | Odd |
+-----+------+-----+
|  1  |   2  |  3  |
+-----+------+-----+`

How to query the `numeric` value of the `string` based on if `odd` or `even` the `string` is in database?

Comment: Could you, perhaps, show us how you want your data to be outputed in tabular format? That would help us to provide correct answer.

Comment: Done Sir. I hope you do understand what I want to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not clear for me. You mix SQL data structures and Python data structures and it is not clear if this will be called from Python or from SQL. Your query should contain some code you are trying to execute.

With such a simple data in your SQL tables you can think of SQL tables as of Python dictionaries. `NUMSTR` dict represents you first SQL table, and I change `X` list of tuples into dict:

```
NUMSTR = {1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three'}
X = {'three': 'odd', 'one': 'odd', 'two': 'even'}

def show_even_odd(in_numbers):
    numbers_info = []
    for i in in_numbers:
        try:
            num_name = NUMSTR[i]
            eo = X[num_name]
        except KeyError:
            eo = '???'
        numbers_info.append(eo)
    print(' | '.join(['%4s' % x for x in numbers_info]))
    print(' | '.join(['%4s' % x for x in in_numbers]))


def test():
    show_even_odd([1, 2, 3])
```

I stored data in `numbers_info` to display it in one line. It would be easier to show info about each number in separate line.

**EDIT**

If your problem is to get first value of each tuple and display its numeric value then such code looks like:

```
X = [('three','odd'), ('one','odd'), ('two','even')]
for nn, eo in X:
    print('%s - %s' % (get_number(nn), eo))
```

Now you must define `get_number()` function. With global `cursor` this may work:

```
def get_number(number_name):
    result = number_name
    cursor.execute('SELECT numeric FROM my_table WHERE String = ?', number_name)
    for txt in cursor.fetchall():
        result = txt[0]
    return result
```

PS In this code I used `?` in `SELECT` to make prepared statement. It should be replaced with `number_name` by ODBC driver. Such operation can be done by Python: `"SELECT ... WHERE String = '%s'" % (number_name)`, but prepared statements are much better. They prevent against SQL Injection and database can better cache query plan for such statements.

Comment: Sorry sir, maybe I gave a wrong example. I am using SQL Server as my database and Im using pypyodbc to connect python into my database so data will be retrieved from SQL. I didnt use the dictionary of python. From my example above, `X = [(‘three’,’odd’), (‘one’,’odd’), (‘two’,’even’)]`, I want to access the first element of each tuples, and display their `numeric` value. Let's just say that the datatype of `numeric` column is `varchar`.

Comment: Try to make some code that shows your problem. It is easier to work on examples. Also divide your big problem into smaller problems, example: "1. how to get first element of each tuple?", "2. how to make prepared query to SQL database?", "3. how to print firsts elements of tuples in one line, and seconds in second line?"