# How to query in database using the value of dictionary in python?

Tags: python-2.7, sorting, dictionary, key-value, pypyodbc

For example I have my dictionary: `my_dict = {'2':'even','1':'odd','3':'odd'}`  And this is my database:

`+---------+--------+
| Numeric | String |
+---------+--------+
|    5    |  five  |
|    4    |  four  |
|    3    |  three |
|    2    |  two   |
|    1    |  one   |
+---------+--------+`

In `my_dict` dictionary,using their `keys`, I want to get their `String` value in my database (SQL SERVER) and using their `values`, sort their `String` value in this sequence:

`odd - even - odd` to be liked this

`one two three`.

And print the output like this: `Let's count one two three`. Actually I just based from Jisoo's question [Querying a list of tuples in Database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28875863/4501264) coz we're quite similar but in mine, is about dictionary.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the intended sorting order? Because `('even', 'odd', 'odd')` has no total order, i.e. the order would be ambiguous the way I read it.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry I didn't realize it that way. Let's just disregard the sequence and sorting instead using their values, display the `String` values of the `keys` to be like this `two is divisible by 2, one is not divisible by 2, three is not divisible by 2`.

Answer (score 0):

There's two sides to this question: The first one is the SQL query part. That is the simpler one:

Assuming the database table is something like

```
 CREATE TABLE number (value INTEGER, name STRING);
```

the SQL is more or less straightforward

```
 from contextlib import closing

 [...]

 my_dict = {'2':'even','1':'odd','3':'odd'}

 # database connection dbc, see python dbapi
 with closing(dbc.cursor()) as cur:
     cur.execute('SELECT value, name FROM number WHERE value IN (1, 2, 3)')
     for value, name in cur:              
         print "%s is %s" % (name, my_dict[str(value)])
```

The python problem here is to get the dictionary keys into the SQL `IN` clause as this is not directly possible with DBAPI2 parameter expansion (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253494/passing-param-to-db-execute-for-where-in-int-list)).

Hence:

```
 my_dict = {'2':'even','1':'odd','3':'odd'}

 # database connection dbc, see python dbapi
 with closing(dbc.cursor()) as cur:
     stmt = 'SELECT value, name FROM number WHERE id IN (%s)' % ','.join('?' for i in my_dict))
     cur.execute(stmt, my_dict.keys())
     for value, name in cur:              
         print "%s is %s" % (name, my_dict[str(value)])
```

One also that the `'?'` is dependent on the paramstyle of the database involved.

Comment: I'm using odbc's `pypyodbc` connection sir. Can that be possible?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help you there. Tagging `pypyodbc` in your question might help, though.

Comment: Thank you Sir for giving answer. I think I should try the dbc to see how it works.